# How to pass a value from a custom dropdown component to react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using `react-hook-form` for validation in forms of this Gatsby project but my dropdown component is not a `<select>` tag but a custom component made with divs and an unordered list. This is completely a design choice because we needed it very customized. Here it is the component

```
// Dropdown.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../../sass/components/forms/dropdown.sass"


export function Dropdown({ preambulo, name, options, placeholder, value}) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
    
  const toggling = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  const onOptionClicked = value => () => {
    setSelectedOption(value);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <span>{preambulo}</span>
      <div 
        className={`
          dropdownHeader 
          ${isOpen === true ? 'open' : 'closed'} 
          `} 
          onClick={toggling}
          >
        {selectedOption || placeholder}
      </div>
      {isOpen && (
        <div 
          className="dropdownListContainer">
            <ul 
              className="dropdownList"
              name={name}
              id={name}
              value={value}
              >
              {options.map((option, i) => (
                <li 
                  className={`dropdownListItem item-${i}`} 
                  key={i} 
                  onClick={onOptionClicked(option)}>
                  {option}
                </li>
              ))}
              <hr />
            </ul>
        </div>
        )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Explaining it a little, the props are passed from a `<Controller>` in `react-hook-form` where the component is rendered. The component itself has a state for dealing with the list that will be opened as the user clicks on the header. Very simple: `const toggling = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);` does it. And the values for options are being mapped from a const passed on parent element, then once something is selected, it takes place in the header just as a `<select>` does.

[image: Gif showing the behavior of the dropdown]

Here it is the code for the form (Edit2):

```
// contato.js
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

//Form Components
import { Dropdown } from "../../components/forms/Dropdown"
import { Input, TextArea } from "../../components/forms/Input"

const ContatoFull = ({ className }) => {
 
  const cargos = [
    {//** values **/}
  ]

  const estados = [
    "Acre",
    "Alagoas",
    "Amazonas",
    "Amapá",
    "Bahia",
    "Ceará",
    "Distrito Federal",
    "Espírito Santo",
    "Goiás",
    "Maranhão",
    "Minas Gerais",
    "Mato Grosso do Sul",
    "Mato Grosso",
    "Pará",
    "Paraíba",
    "Pernambuco",
    "Piauí",
    "Paraná",
    "Rio de Janeiro",
    "Rio Grande do Norte",
    "Rondônia",
    "Roraima",
    "Rio Grande do Sul",
    "Santa Catarina",
    "Sergipe",
    "São Paulo",
    "Tocantins"
  ]
  const methods = useForm();
  const { handleSubmit, control, formState, errors } = methods;
  
  const onSubmit = data => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
  
  console.log(formState);

  return (
    <form 
      method="post"
      className={`${className !== 0 ? className : ''}`} 
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      
      <div
        className={`dropdownContainer cargo`}>
        <Controller
          name="cargo"
          control={control}
          render={({ onClick, name, value }) =>
          <Dropdown 
            onClick={e => onClick(e.target.value)}
            value={value}
            preambulo="Eu sou" 
            placeholder="Placeholder" 
            name={name}
            options={cargos}
            />
          }
        />
      </div>

      <div
        className={`dropdownContainer estado`}>
        <Controller
          name="estado"
          control={control}
          render={({ onClick, name, value }) =>
          <Dropdown 
            onClick={e => onClick(e.target.value)}
            value={value}
            name={name}
            preambulo="Estou em/no" 
            placeholder="acre" 
            options={estados}
              />
          }
        />
      </div>

      <div 
        className={`inputContainer empresa`}>
        <Controller 
          name="empresa" 
          type="text "
          control={control}
          defaultValue=""
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ onChange, value, name, type, label }) =>
          <Input 
            onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
            value={value}
            label="Nome da minha empresa" 
            type="text" />
          }
        />
        {errors.empresa && <span className="erro requerido">Campo obrigatório</span>}
        
        
      </div>

      {//** more input components //*^}

      <button 
        type="submit" 
        className="simpleButton primary submit button">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default ContatoFull
```

Now, there are two problems we dealing with: 1) how to pass a value to the form, since we're not using a standard tag for selection; <s>and 2) that even though the toggling works for clicking on header or selecting an option from the list, clicking outside won't close it, as you can see below.</s>

[image: Gif showing the problem #2]

I'm not sure on how to tackle any of these matters. I believe that problem #1 would need a hook for fetching the child component selected value, but have no clue on what would this hook be nor how to use it with react-hook-form. <s>And for problem #2, perhaps a function that captures click outside that would toggle back the opened list. Thing is that I've managed to target the header but not the outside of it, or "not-header" part, if that's a thing.</s>

**Edit**: managed to detect click outside using this lib: [react-outside-click-handler](https://github.com/airbnb/react-outside-click-handler). Great solution for a simple problem.

**Edit 2**: Reading the comment from @dshung1997 I've realized I didn't pasted the code for the parent component here. Just correcting this. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. I thought passing a value to the form is seemingly obvious. If not, mind if you put some more words?

Comment: Sure. In the component Dropdown the value is set by the option selected but I can't or couldn't make this same value to be passed to console on submit. I mean, the form is not getting any changes from child component.  It might be obvious but I'm not getting it. I'm not that much of a coder. :(

Comment: Hmm. I think you want to pass a value to Dropdown, which will be updated when you select an item. Right? If so, you'll need 2 things. Value and a function to update it. Just like the ordinary <select> (value and onChange). You can have `[value, setValue] = useState()` and pass both value and setValue to Dropdown. :D

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood this but isn't it the other way around? The child component `<Dropdown>` already have such function (or something like it) in `[selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null)` to set the "initial option", then `onOptionClick = value => () => {...}` changes the state of selectedOption so it would appear properly on header, you know, emulation a `<select>` behavior. I'm wondering if it's the same you're telling me about or if I'm wrong. The goal would be to fetch this `selectedOption` value on parent component so the form posts it on submit?

Comment: Having local state inside Dropdown depends mainly on your preference. But yeah, I understand your point. Let me write an answer

Answer (score -1):

If you need to fetch the selectedOption to the parent, first you're assuming the parent is the source of truth and that's why you have to give the Dropdown a function.

Say we use a select tag, it would be like this

```
export const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("1");
  return (
    <select value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  );
};
```

So we need a variable for the value (value) and a function to update that value (setValue).

"The goal would be to fetch this selectedOption value on parent component so the form posts it on submit?". Only the parent know when the form is submitted. The dropdown shouldn't and needn't know for sure. Goal is to tell the parent to update the value as soon as it is changed, not that give the value to parent when it submits.

Thus, you need to provide Dropdown a function to update the value.

Comment: Ok! I believe I got it now. Will be working on this for the next hours and will return with a conclusion - or not.Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: No problem. Let me know your result :)

Comment: Just to let you my feedback: couldn't make it work. Used a lib to render a working dropdown. Thanks anyway!